# Troubleshooting Feature (1) has invalid geometry

Tags: qgis, training

I am using Training manual 6.2.9.

I've stumbled upon the following error referring to invalid geometry in Feature 1.

What is feature 1 and how do I troubleshoot this error?

```
Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Extract by location' finished
QGIS version: 3.12.3-București
QGIS code revision: 8234261527
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 3.0.4
GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Extract by location' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'INPUT' : 'C:/Users/JOEBLOGS/Documents/vector_analysis.gpkg|layername=Buildings_34S', 'INTERSECT' : 'C:\\Users\\JOEBLOGS\\Documents\\vector_analysis.gpkg|layername=road_schools_buffer_intersection', 'OUTPUT' : 'ogr:dbname=\'C:/Users/JOEBLOGS/Documents/vector_analysis.gpkg\' table=\"well_located_houses\" (geom)', 'PREDICATE' : [0] }

Feature (1) has invalid geometry. Please fix the geometry or change the Processing setting to the "Ignore invalid input features" option.
Execution failed after 0.28 seconds

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Extract by location' finished
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feature 1 refers to the first geometry of your layer that the algorithm tried to work on.

To solve this, just go to the process toolbox, then vector geometry and run Fix geometries on the input layer

[image]

This will generate a new layer, corrected, with which you will work